# Kotlin detect linter: how to include detektTest into detect gradle step?

Tags: kotlin, detect

The question is about io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt linter for Kotlin.
By default "detektMain" step includes into "detect" step, "detect" step includes into "check" gradle step. My final goal is to include "detektTest" into "check".